Need help identifying a Grohe shower valve so I can replace the cartridges
Grohe Shower Valve

This is the Grohe Shower Valve that I need help in locating model. 20 years old.

Somebody might recognize the trim, but the foolproof method would be to disassemble the unit, pull out the cartridge and read the part number on the cartridge.
